# VirtualBox Share permissions

Tags: windows, mount, fstab

At the moment I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 on top of a VirtualBox running as service in Microsoft Windows7 x64. I've configured the shares on `fstab` with

```
E /media/E vboxsf auto,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

the mount is OK

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 knoker knoker 16384 Sep  1 20:02 E
```

but I cant change the permissions inside of `/media/E`, `chmod` runs but doesn't do nothing.

On a specific case `/media/E/Docs/Downloads` I have

```
dr-xr-xr-x 1 knoker knoker     163840 Sep  1 19:30 Downloads
```

and since I can't seem to be able to change from Linux, I tried it on the Windows, and all users listed have full control.

Any ideas on what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

why argue with stupid... 
i solved it by creating another folder, copying the content of the downloads to the new folder, deleted the downloads folder and renamed the new folder downloads, and BAM:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 knoker knoker 98304 Sep 2 00:07 downloads
```

this is not the perfect solution but it works tho... As of why i was having the problem in the first place is still a mystery...